# Understanding raw socket packet header

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have written a socket packet sniffer in Python using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634494/packet-sniffer-in-python).

```
import socket, struct

# Setup socket object
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
s.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 0))
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

Id = 0
while (True):
    data = s.recvfrom(65565)
    packet = data[0]
    address = data[1]
    header = struct.unpack("!BBHHHBBHBBBBBBBB", packet[:20])

    if (header[6] == 6):
        protocol = "TCP"
    elif (header[6] == 17):
        protocol = "UDP"

    print("Number: ", Id, end="\t")
    print("Protocol: ", protocol, end="\t")
    print("Address: ", address, end="")
    print("Header: ", header)
    #print("Data: ", data)
    print()
    Id += 1
```

1. I know I can find the receivers IP address at index 0 of the data variable (data[0]), but where in the packet would i find the senders IP address and port number?
2. What do all the integers in the header tuple mean? I know header[6] is the protocol TCP/UDP, but what about the rest?

   Header: (69, 0, 61, 1541, 0, 128, 17, 0, 192, 168, 56, 1, 255, 255, 255, 255)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP header has a [well-defined structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header) and an [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#page-11). You decided to unpack it with bytes and shorts. Generally speaking, you want to match the size of each field with the correct data type. Taking a look at the proper header size, you can see the individual breakdown:

```
    0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |Version|  IHL  |Type of Service|          Total Length         |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |         Identification        |Flags|      Fragment Offset    |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |  Time to Live |    Protocol   |         Header Checksum       |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                       Source Address                          |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    Destination Address                        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    Options                    |    Padding    |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

This can be done programmatically as:

```
struct.unpack('!BBHHHBBHII')
# alternatively:
struct.unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s')
```

I prefer the latter because you can fairly easily convert it to an IP address:

Example Ethernet header:

```
0000   3c 4a 92 1f 04 00 74 c6 3b 8d 82 69 08 00 45 00  <J....t.;..i..E.
0010   00 3c 0a 24 40 00 40 06 23 76 0a 14 01 0d 01 01  .<.$@.@.#v......
0020   01 01 e7 7a 04 d2 a2 5e 0c d2 00 00 00 00 a0 02  ...z...^........
0030   72 10 0d 51 00 00 02 04 05 b4 04 02 08 0a 9c d4  r..Q............
0040   c0 c0 00 00 00 00 01 03 03 07                    ..........
```

the 20-byte IPv4 header exists at `packet[14:34]`. Unpacking it with the above format yields this:

```
>>> header = struct.unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s', packet[14:34])
>>> header
(69, 0, 60, 2596, 16384, 64, 6, 9078, b'\n\x14\x01\r', b'\x01\x01\x01\x01')
```

Indices 8 and 9 are the source and destination IP's respectively. Because they are bytes, we can convert them to `int` and then `str` to get the IP in string format:

```
# Note: Python 3 only
>>> ip_src = '.'.join(map(str, header[8]))  # 10.20.1.13
>>> ip_dst = '.'.join(map(str, header[9]))  # 1.1.1.1
```

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, where is the conversion to `int`?

Comment: I mis-spoke. In python 3, iterating through a byte string will automatically turn each byte into an `int`. The value of `\n`is 0x0a or 10 in decimal. `map(str, ...)` will convert it to `"10"` instead of `10`.

Comment: I assumed he's using python3 because I saw no `print_function` import

Comment: Yeah, im using Python 3. The destination address does not match my computers or routers IP address in `ipconfig`, and when I `ping` the source and destination addresses in cmd.exe I get 'Request timed out.'

Comment: You did not answer question fully. What about port number? How do I get a packets port.

Comment: I provided you with two references for the IPv4 packet header. Port numbers have no meaning in terms of IPv4 as they are transport-layer constructs. In order to find the port numbers, determine the transport protocol and parse the TCP/UDP headers accordingly.

Comment: You should download [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and watch some packet traffic that is visually intuitive. The transport layer header immediately follows the IP header. However, note that both IP and TCP have optional fields that should be accounted for. UDP header size is static (checksum field is "optional," but still accounted for by setting to all 0's).

Comment: @Goodies Grate Answer, You said  "you want to match the size of each field with the correct data type." Where I check and  get the  correct type for this protocol others protocol like ethernet ('!6s6sH').